# Loop cat walks video continuously | Adobe premiere

Tags: adobe, adobe-premiere

I bought  **[this video](http://www.shutterstock.com/fr/video/clip-1405087-stock-footage-cat-walks-from-right-side-of-screen-to-left-side.html?src=/eB0GRlD3iaEucrTvazcjQQ:1:0/3p)** where cat walks, I want to know if possible how to loop the video like the cat walks continuously ? 
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try to edit the video so that the cat is walking and starts/ends close to the same position. Then you can create a subclip and paste it down several times with a morph dissolve if you're using it for a current project, or you can do that and export the clip as a gif if you're just looking for something cute for your Tumblr.

Depending on the video, you might end up only being able to use one cycle of steps to keep the cat in a similar position. This is why I'd suggest the morph dissolve, so that it doesn't jitter as badly. Due to the nature of walking, you might have to spend quite a bit of time to get a smooth transition. Something to break the viewer's eyeline to the cat can help by giving you more room to reset the loop more smoothly, and in that case you would slide the new video in along the fault line, instead of morphing it.

I use Premiere Pro 2015 & now 2017, so I don't know if all this will hold true for older versions.

Comment: Just saw the video. If the morph doesn't do the trick, you might experiment with cropping the video of the back half of the cat and adding that to a cropped video of the front, morph the two halves independently and get your loop that way.